# How to find out the cause of an Oracle deadlock

Tags: sql, oracle, database-deadlocks

When testing my application with multiple users, I have encountered an ORA-00060 deadlock error. I'm not sure how to determine the cause of this error, so if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

I looked in the trace file generated for this event and it shows me which query caused this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET CK=CK+1 WHERE A_ID=(
    SELECT A_ID FROM TABLE_B WHERE SOME_COLUMN=:SOMECOLUMN
)
```

It also generated this:

```
[Transaction Deadlock]

The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-0002a675-00000000        51     200    SX   SSX       52      22    SX   SSX
TM-0002a675-00000000        52      22    SX   SSX       51     200    SX   SSX

session 200: DID 0001-0033-0000014A session 22: DID 0001-0034-0000005A 
session 22: DID 0001-0034-0000005A  session 200: DID 0001-0033-0000014A 

Rows waited on:
  Session 200: obj - rowid = 0002A6B1 - AAAqaxAAUAAAAFTAAA
  (dictionary objn - 173745, file - 20, block - 339, slot - 0)
  Session 22: obj - rowid = 0002A6B1 - AAAqaxAAUAAAAFTAAA
  (dictionary objn - 173745, file - 20, block - 339, slot - 0)
```

How do I use the above information to find out what caused the problem? There aren't any unindexed foreign keys on either TABLE_A or TABLE_B (which I believe is commonly the cause of this type of error).

When I run this query:

```
SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE 
FROM DBA_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = 173745;
```

I get the name of a primary key on a completely different table! Could this be a clue as to why the deadlock is happening?

Comment: I think you're question is on-topic for Stack Overflow, but just wanted to make sure you're aware of [dba.se]. There maybe someone knowledge people on that site about these types of issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the enqueue involved is a 'TM' enqueue, and because the mode the lock is being held is 'SX' and the mode the lock is waited on is 'SSX', I can tell you, with absolute certainty, that this is due to a foreign key relationship, where the referring table (child table) column is not indexed.  If you look for unindexed foreign keys and add indexes, this problem should disappear.

Hope that helps....

P.S.  My presentation, "Understanding and Interpreting Deadlocks, or, What to do with an ORA-00060", is available for download at the OakTable site, http://www.oaktable.net.  Look in the "Contributed Files" section.

Comment: Yes, this was the cause of the problem. I used Tom Kyte's query (http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4530093713805#26568859366976) to find all the unindexed foreign keys and fixed them, which has solved the problem. I still don't quite understand *why* unindexed foreign keys cause this to happen - I'm hoping your presentation can shed some light on this! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, my presentation doesn't go into the details of why unindexed foreign keys cause locking problems.  My presentation comes at the problem somewhat pragmatically.  If you are faced with an ORA-00060, let's look at the tracefile, specifically, the deadlock graph, the SQLs involved in the deadlock, and the rows involved in the deadlock, and try to definitively determine the root cause of the deadlock.

Comment: If you're interested in learning *why* locking works the way it does and why unindexed foreign keys cause locking problems, you're probably better off looking at the Oracle documentation.  Specifically, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/datainte.htm#CNCPT1657

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at that too. Just out of interest, is there ever a situation in which you *wouldn't* want to index a foreign key? And if not, why doesn't Oracle automatically create an index when you create a foreign key, as I'm pretty sure it does for primary keys?

Comment: Personally, I *always* index FKs.  If you look here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/consist.htm#CNCPT88978 you'll see that Oracle *strongly* suggests it, but discusses one specific case that may allow you to not create the index.  In general, I think it's a good idea, unless you're really trying to tune your system to the nth degree, and you're really concerned about scalability issues.  Usually, the benefit of the extra index more than makes up for any overhead or loss of scalability.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. Thinking about it, I have had problems with unindexed foreign keys before but in a slightly different context. When deleting from the parent table it did a full-table scan on the child table (which had ~20 million rows in it), causing terrible performance. I think I will index all my foreign keys as a matter of course from now on!

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, but I've just finished reading your "What to do when you encounter ORA-00060" document (in the zip file on oaktable.net). At the bottom of page 3 you describe a situation which will cause a deadlock. I have tried it and can confirm that it does cause a deadlock, and I think I understand why now, but I just wanted to make sure by running it past you. Here's my understanding:
Session 1: "delete from child where child_id = 1". This session acquires a row-level lock.
Session 2: "delete from child where child_id = 2". This session acquires a row-level lock.

Comment: Session 1: "delete from parent where parent_id = 1". This session acquires a row-level lock on the parent table, and tries to acquire a full table lock on the child table, which it can't because session 2 has a row-level lock.
Session 2: "delete from parent where parent_id = 2". This session acquires a row-level lock on the parent table and tries to acquire a full table lock on the child table, which it can't because session 1 has a row-level lock. At this point session 1 and session 2 are blocking eachother, causing the deadlock.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  In that situation, if there were no deadlock detection, those two sessions would be stuck forever.

Comment: Was hoping to learn from your insights, but `oaktable.net` just brings up a bare Nginx page now.

Comment: Yes, the OakTable is still active, but oaktable.net is dead.  It's been *years* since I wrote that preentation.  Let me see if I can find it.  I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok, found it buried in my GDrive!  This is ancient, but I think the cases are all still valid.  There may be some new situations, but I can't think of any.  Antyhow. try this link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2t_l1d1imCbdkZrMmMtNXpiUWs/view?usp=share_link&resourcekey=0-NcnAfGFog2OQSG8OiMX90Q