# ORA-00060 while running multiple DELETE queries on one table

Tags: oracle, database-deadlocks

I have a multi-user application, which allows many users to perform DML operations on Database tables. Under a particular scenario, 2 users are trying to perform DELETE on one Table through different transactions.

The problem is, transaction 1 is a long running one, and acquires Row Lock on the Table for a long period of time. So transaction 2(attempting to modify the same rows) errors out with ORA-00060. 
Also, I cannot do an Execute Immediate for DELETE queries on transaction 1, sue to some data integrity issues.

How can I modify DELETE query to mimic something like the behavior of NOLOCK in SQL Server?

Comment: See [Understanding Oracle deadlock](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/02/25/understanding-oracle-deadlock/).

Comment: What you are explaining should not encounter `deadlock`, it will only `lock` the rows which are yet to be committed/rolled back. A deadlock occurs when two or more sessions are waiting for data locked by each other, resulting in all the sessions being blocked.

Comment: Ok. I just found out that transaction 1 is part of a nested transaction. Is that causing the deadlock?

Comment: If it is same session, then NO.

Comment: I suggest to look at the alert log, the trace file generated will have all the details.

Comment: "execute immediate" is not relevant to this.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a child table (or perhaps a grandchild table) that has an unindexed foreign key. See [How to find out the cause of an Oracle deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474959/how-to-find-out-the-cause-of-an-oracle-deadlock)

Otherwise, the trace file may tell you which rows are involved, see: 
[How can I identify the rows involved in an Oracle deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577000/how-can-i-identify-the-rows-involved-in-an-oracle-deadlock)